# Why is gitlab asking me to enter my user credentials?

Tags: git, gitlab

git is asking me to enter my gitlab user credentials when pushing or pulling code. I am using gitlab.com, I'm not self-hosting gitlab.

I followed the instructions to set up my ssh key. I created a key, I copied the contents from ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, added the key to gitlab using gitlab's user interface, and git still asks me for my user and password.

```
git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.com/<my_user>/<my_repo> (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/<my_user>/<my_repo> (push)
```

Comment: You need to use an SSH URL, not an HTTPS one.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are using HTTPS authentication.  Switch to an SSH-based URL (in this case, probably `ssh://git@gitlab.com/path/to/repo.git` or `git@gitlab.com:path/to/repo.git`).  For instance:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@gitlab.com/<user>/<repo>
```

(Alternatively, if you're comfortable with using your configured editor, you can run `git config --edit` and edit the URL directly in the configuration file.  Make sure whatever editor you choose stores files in plain-text format, not any enhanced rich-text or UTF-16 encoding.)

#### Background

In order to connect one Git to another, you may need to authenticate yourself.  There are several ways to do that.  (Whether you need to do that depends on the kind of connection you are making, and whether the repository is public.)

If you are authenticating over `https://`, your Git may ask for a user name and password.  It can use various credential helpers, which may also *store* user names and/or passwords. You can configure which credential helper to use, including the "cache" and "store" helpers, which use different additional data. Note that the available set of credential helpers varies based on your underlying operating system as well.

If you are authenticating over `ssh://`, you will use an ssh key (SSH authentication).

If you use a URL that begins with `user@host:`, you are using SSH authentication.

Comment: This command can be used to change HTTPS URL to SSH: "git remote git@gitlab.com:myuser/myrepo.git"

Answer (score 1):

To avoid entering credentials every time to connect with gitlab simply make us of access tokens and change your `remote origin` HTTP URL to use your new api token as follow

```
git remote set-url origin https://oauth2:TOKEN@ANY_GIT_PROVIDER_DOMAIN/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_REPO.git
```